# Greens theorem on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 16$.

Tags: calculus, integration, greens-theorem

> Use Greens theorem to calculate the area enclosed by the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 16$.

I'm confused on which part is $P$ and which part is $Q$ to use in the following equation

$$\iint\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right){\rm d}A$$

Comment: What have you tried? Could you tell us what you might integrate over the region of the circle to calculate its integral? Can you tell us how you might phrase it to match Green’s theorem?

Comment: I think the problem with this question is that it’s so easy that it isn’t obvious how to fit Green’s theorem into it, especially when you can just write down the answer of $16\pi.$

Comment: Well my idea was to use x^2 as P and y^2 as Q but that would give me zeros

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to take $Q  =0$ and $P =-y$ then $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1$ and by Green formula we get,
$$ \iint_{x^2+y^2\le4^2} 1dxdy =\iint_{x^2+y^2\le4^2}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dxdy= -\oint_{x^2+y^2=4^2} ydx  =\\- 16\int_0^{2\pi} \sin td(\cos t)= 16\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 t dt= 16\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-\cos (2t)}{2}dt= \color{red}{ 16\pi}$$
Where we used the parametrization, $$x= 4\cos t~~~and ~~y =4\sin t$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You want

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1$$

so the integral is

$$\iint_{x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 16}{\rm d}A$$

Can you find $P$ and $Q$ that satisfy this? Notice that there is more than one choice.